# Get Sql Dates excluding weekend and Null values before 3 months from current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table consists of

(
D1 datetime,d2 datetime,....,d31 datetime,H1 int, h2 int,..h31 int
)

D1- Dates of month, H1 - Hours

here i want to get the date for which hours are <= 0, and the date should not be sunday or saturday, this should be for past 3months.

I have tried like getting all the sundays and saturdays list of past 3months and checking in that list, but it could not help.

Please help me through this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (d1, h1), (d2, h2), . . . 
     ) v(d, h)
where v.d >= dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) and  -- last three months
      datename(weekday, v.d) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') and
      v.h < 0;
```

The `cross apply` is being used to unpivot your data.  This is a hint that your data structure is really lousy.  The data that you have in columns should be in separate rows.